# Is there a version of Primary Decomposition Theorem for infinite-dimensional vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

From *Linear Algebra* from Hoffman and Kunze's book, page 220.

> Let T be a linear operator on the finite-dimensional vector space V
>   over the field F. Let $m_T=p_1^{r_1}\dots p_k^{r_k}$ be the minimal
>   polynomial for $T$, where $p_{i}$ are distinct irreducible monic
>   polynomials over $\mathbb{F}$ and $r_{i}$ are positive numbers. Let
>   $W_{i}$ be the null space of $p_{i}(T)^{r_{i}},\,\,i=1,\dots, k$. Then
>
> (i)    $V=W_1\oplus \cdots \oplus W_k$;
>
> (ii)  each $W_{i}$ is $T$-invariant;
>
> (iii) if $T_{i}$ is the operator induced on $W_{i}$ by $T$, then the
>   minimal polynomial for $T_{i}$ is $p_{i}^{r_{i}}$.

Is there a version of Primary Decomposition Theorem for infinite-dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: Well, the first problem is that the minimal polynomial need not exist (consider $T$ acting on the polynomial ring $k[T]$ by left multiplication). If a minimal polynomial does exist, then the statement should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to what Qiaochu wrote, you are probably looking for the notion of "algebraic operators".

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and $A$ a bounded linear operator. $A$ is said to be *algebraic* if there exists a polynomial such that $p(A) = 0$. It can be shown that when $A$ is algebraic there exists a minimal polynomial $p_X$.

What is true: $A$ is algebraic if and only if $X$ is the union of all its finite dimensional invariant subspaces. (And on each finite dimensional invariant subspace you can apply the finite dimensional theorem.)

What is also true: on each finite dimensional subspace $V$ the minimal polynomial $p_V$ divides $p_A$.

For statements of this form or more, you can consult [Radjavi and Rosenthal](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2003221), *Invariant Subspaces*, Chapter 4; [Kaplansky](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=93654)'s *Introduction to Differential Algebra*; and [Przeworska-Rolewicz](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=493449)'s *Equations with Transformed Argument*, Chapter 2.